# dkh, uid and af_v parameters In android

Tags: android, android-logcat

In an android interview I was asked to extract the source code from apk file of app and then find how dkh , uid & af_v  parameters are generated in the code . I have searched a lot but not able to find what are these parameters & how they are generated . I only got that dkh is found in logcat . Can someone explain me in detail these parameters.

Comment: None of those are part of the android SDK in any way.  It sounds more like they were doing a practical test of your reverse engineering skills than anything else.  In which case we aren't going to find an answer without their apk.

Comment: @GabeSechan i got dkh and uid from this link [https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=69604&aid=696040004000&name=browser_crashlog.txt&token=ABZ6GAcrbhah9VqrFJ7ltHTJBGBEvtmJpw%3A1400221036205] can you help me with it

Comment: ProGuard was used to obfuscate the code. It can only be de-obfuscated if you have those mappings files which are generated after running ProGuard.